# How to configure message Time-To-Live in MSMQ?

Tags: msmq

Does anyone know if it is possible to configure the message time-to-live in MSMQ? So that the messages are moved to the dead letter queue once the time-to-live is elapsed. I know there is some default value, but I don't know where it is and how to change it.

Just want to emphasise that I know how to do it programmatically when sending message to a queue. But I need to change it in the MSMQ. Would be great for each queue, but if not possible, for the whole MSMQ.

I found the LongLiveTime parameter in the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/MSMQ/Parameters/MachineCache/), which is by default set to 345600 (seconds? = 4 days). I changed this value to 30 (seconds) and restarted the machine, but it did not work. More than that, this value was automatically returned back to 345600.

Can it be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To set the Time-To-Reach-Queue (TTRQ), for a server see [Set the default lifetime for messages](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754460.aspx):

> You can use this procedure to set the default lifetime for Message
> Queuing messages. The lifetime of a Message Queuing message specifies
> the maximum time interval for a message to reach a destination queue.
> If this time interval is exceeded before the message reaches the
> destination queue then the message is placed in the deadletter queue
> if the PROPID_M_JOURNAL property of the message is set to
> MQMSG_DEADLETTER.
>
> Membership in \Domain Users, or equivalent, is the minimum
> required to complete this procedure.
>
> To set the default lifetime for Message Queuing messages:
>
> Click Start, point to Programs, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Active Directory Sites and Services.
>
> On the View menu, click Show Services Node.
>
> In the console tree, right-click MsmqServices.
>
> Where? - Active Directory Sites and Services/Services/MsmqServices
>
> Click Properties.
>
> On the General page, type a new value and select new units as needed.

Edit:

The only way to set the TTBR - Time-To-Be-Received - is when sending the message, as it [includes the time taken for the message to reach the destination queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711430.aspx):

> In each hop, Message Queuing subtracts the time elapsed on the
> applicable computer from MaxTimeToReceive when it dispatches the
> message to the next computer, where a new timer is set. After a
> message arrives at the destination queue, MaxTimeToReceive can be used
> to find out how much time remains in the time-to-be-received timer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is not what I need. I need to set the timeout for the message to be in the destination queue so that if the message is not picked up by the recipient within this time, it is moved to the dead letter queue.